# Question on Identity Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

> Suppose $B$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix satisfying $AB = B+I$, where $$A = \begin{bmatrix}4&2\\2&3\end{bmatrix}$$ Find B.

Answer (score 4):

$$AB = B+I \implies AB - B = I \implies AB - IB = I \implies (A-I)B=I \\ \implies (A-I)^{-1} = B$$

Comment: Just want to make sure, how did you go from AB-BI=I to the next one?

Comment: @JanoyCresva At no point did I write $AB-BI = I$.  I wrote $AB-IB = I$.  It doesn't make a difference in this case because $I$ commutes with all square matrices, but remember that matrix multiplication isn't commutative in general so usually you can't just switch two factors.  But as for how I got the part after that, I factored out the $B$ on the right.

Answer (score 1):

$AB=B+I$

-> $(A-I)B=I$

$A-I=\begin{bmatrix}3&2\\2&2\end{bmatrix}$

$B=\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\-1&\frac{3}{2}\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: I'm confused how you got (A-I)B

Comment: $AB=B+I$ implies $AB-B=I$; but, $AB-B=(A-I)B$.

Answer (score 0):

A summary of the other answers. Hopefully this clears things up.

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
AB = B+I &\iff AB - B = I \\
&\iff AB - IB = I \\
&\iff (A-I)B=I.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$\det(A - I) =6-4=2\neq 0$, and therefore $A-I$ has an inverse. Hence
$$B = (A-I)^{-1}.$$